# Grabbing a filter value via CEWP code behind

Tags: javascript, filter, content-editor-web-part, connected-web-parts, query

I have employed a Query String Filter to parse a value and send it to a chart web part.
now I would like to use this value in a CEWP to provide an explaination/clarification for the chart,  but the CEWP does not allow connections.

Is there a way to grab this value from the Chart or Filter in the CEWP embeded javascript.  ( Designer is not available where I work )

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use JQuery to get the filter by partial id. `SPTextSlicerValueTextControl` is the end of the ID of a SharePoint text filter input field.

`filterValue = $('input[id*=SPTextSlicerValueTextControl]');`

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
function GetValue(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( unescape(window.location.href) );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

Source: http://kancharla-sharepoint.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/javascript-code-to-get-query-string.html

Comment: This would be a fine way to grab the value from the URL.

Comment: I raised the question because I was looking for a way to access the Filter value from the Chart Web Part or from the Query Filter Web Part.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought that's what the Query String Filter Web Part is all about.. if I find something else I'll make sure to post again!

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for? Asked that this week: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59366/how-to-get-value-of-list-filter-web-part-in-javascript

Comment: You can use jquery to find the value: Open firefox+firebug, rightclick/inspect element with firebug. Then $('#id').val