# How to get value of List Filter web part in Javascript?

Tags: 2010, web-part, javascript, filter

I use the SharePoint List Filter web part on a page to control several Data View Web Parts.

How do I read the current value of the List Filter in Javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SharePoint List Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.splistfilterwebpart%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web part is rendered as input text field  for displaying filter value:

```
<input  type="text" readonly="readonly" id="{ClientID}_SpListPicker_SelectionBox" title="Selected values" >
```

and input hidden field for storing filter value:

```
<input type="hidden"  id="{ClientID}_SpListPicker_Selection" value="{FilterValue}">
```

Below are demonstrated several ways how to retrieve filter value on the client side.

### Retrieve filter value from input hidden field (jQuery dependency)

```
function getListFilterValueFromControl()
{
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var filter = j("input[id$='SpListPicker_Selection']");
    return filter.val();
}
```

### Retrieve filter value from context info

`ContextInfo` represents List Info structure on the client side.
Property `overrideFilterQstring` contains filter string in the following format:

`FilterField1={FilterName1}&FilterValue1={FilterValue1}..`

```
function getListFilterValueFromContextInfo()
{
    var filterFields = ctx.overrideFilterQstring.split('&');   //
    if(filterFields.length > 1)
    {
       return filterFields[1].split('=')[1];
    }
    return null;  
}
```

### Usage

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListFilterValueFromControl, 'SP.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you have multiple list filter webparts in your page, here is how to access the value of each of them

```
$("div.ms-WPBody div div:eq(0) span input").val();
```

for your 1st webpart

```
$("div.ms-WPBody div div:eq(1) span input").val();
```

for your second webpart, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Another method I just found after more research:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filterValue = $("div.ms-WPBody div div span input").val();
    if (filterValue != null) {
        alert("filter value is: "+$("div.ms-WPBody div div span"));
    } 
});
```

vgrem provided a more beautiful version though ;)

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sharepointdevelopment/thread/60e6b32d-86a7-4ddc-8f7d-800b58ceb3f9