# How to get value of multiple list filter webparts

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, jquery, filter

Related to the previous post about accessing a List Filter Web Part value [How to get value of List Filter web part in Javascript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59366/how-to-get-value-of-list-filter-web-part-in-javascript/82634#82634)

How do I get access to the value of multiple list filter web part using the `$("div.ms-WPBody div div div span input").val();` approach that works on my first webpart, but only

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to access the value of each webpart

```
$("div.ms-WPBody div div:eq(0) span input").val();
```

for your 1st webpart

```
$("div.ms-WPBody div div:eq(1) span input").val();
```

for your second webpart, and so on